# How to bootRun a gradle project with multiple parameters?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have a Grails application and I want to run the app from command line. I did `bootRun` the app by:

```
gradlew bootRun -Daws_mail_url=someText -s
```

command, but when I want to add the second parameter something like

```
gradlew bootRun -Daws_mail_url=someText -Dapigateway_api_key=sometext -s
```

I get `Unknown command-line option` error. How should I solve it?

[image: screeshot]

Comment: It should just run. Could you please provide stacktrace?

Comment: Sure, I did add it

Comment: You should use single hyphen `-` not double `--`. Try once again.

Comment: Yes, It was just before my eyes. Thanks, that was the problem

Comment: I will add an answer, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing system property with a double hyphen `--`, a single one `-` should be used.